# Problem with loading Bing map in Bird's eye view using UMap AFComponent in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, bing-maps

I am using Umap AFComponent 1.8.1 in Flex 3.5 for showing Bing maps. When I try to load a map in Bird's eye view, map flickers. Fiddler log shows a lot of requests done by the map proxy for different latitude and longitudes. Finally proxy does the request for given location.
How to make the proxy just do the request for given location and not unwanted requests.

This is how map is initialized

```
var map : UMap = new UMap();
map.addControl(new BingControl());
```

Add Bird's eye manager

```
var birdseye = new BirdsEyeManager();
map.addManager(birdseye);
```

Change to Birds eye

```
map.setMapType(birdseye.mapType);
```

Initialize the proxy

```
MapProxy.initialize("../Mapping/Proxy.ashx");
proxy = MapProxy.getInstance();
proxy.getToken();
```

Getting the map location ,loading the map is done by UMap component.

Please help.

Thanks

Note: If I load the map in Road view or Aerial view and then change to Bird's eye it works as expected.